# What is similar method like THREE.WebGLRenderTarget() in Babylon.js

Tags: three.js, babylonjs

Here is code that i want to convert from Three.js to Babylon.js

```
//Three.js

this.texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height);
```

I want to try to porting this function in Babylon.js. If someone have idea, Please let me know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Babylon (I come from the three.js side of the tags you used), but you're probably looking for [`RenderTargetTexture`](https://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.rendertargettexture).

Comment: RenderTargetTexture is just texture and it has MultiRenderTarget but I'm not sure how can i use it

Comment: Some useful information (that you should add to your question) is answering: How do you intend to use the render target? I assumed you wanted to read the pixel data, which can certainly be done from a texture.

Comment: I try to dig with this code and still didn't found solution. Anyway I find out correct answer, I definitely answer my questions.

Comment: I think TheJim01 is right - how do you plan on using it? Eventually, the RenderTargetTexture is your friend. Have you read this - https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/how_to_use_rendertargettexture_and_multiple_passes ?

Comment: Well.... @RaananW, Can you specific how to use RenerTargetTexture which works like WebGLRenderTarget(Three.js) in BabylonJS?

Comment: I don't know threejs well enough to tell you what the WebGLRenderTarget does. and this is why it will be good if you specify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @RaananW [`WebGLRenderTarget`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) is basically a framebuffer. It even has a property, [`texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget.texture), that holds the rendered pixels, and can alternately be read into a buffer using [`WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels). So it all seems to line up if @Handsome is trying to use the rendered pixels, but if that's not the intent, then ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯